# Merge two dataframes but ignore rows with NaT

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, merge

I have two dataframes that I would like to merge on 'ID' and 'updated_date'. The only difference between them is that the 'other_date' column in df1 contains a couple NaT and df2 contains a 'type' column.

Id like the resulting df to have NaN for all merging rows that initially had NaT in them (row#3)

```
    ID   |  updated_date |  other_date | 
0   11   |   2019-04-03  |  2019-04-09 | 
1   11   |   2019-05-02  |  2019-05-14 |
2   11   |   2019-05-20  |  2019-06-05 | 
3   11   |   2019-03-03  |      NaT    |

    ID   |  updated_date |  other_date |   type   |
0   11   |   2019-04-03  |  2019-04-09 |    C     |
1   11   |   2019-05-02  |  2019-05-14 |    C     |
2   11   |   2019-05-20  |  2019-06-05 |    D     |
3   11   |   2019-03-03  |  2019-03-04 |    C     |
```

Desired output:

```
    ID   |  updated_date |  other_date |   type   |
0   11   |   2019-04-03  |  2019-04-09 |    C     |
1   11   |   2019-05-02  |  2019-05-14 |    C     |
2   11   |   2019-05-20  |  2019-06-05 |    D     |
3   11   |   2019-03-03  |      NaT    |   NaN    |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try a left join with the three columns ID, updated_date and other_date?

```
df1.merge(df2, how = "left", on = ["ID", "updated_date", "other_date"])
```

The output

|  | ID | updated_date | other_date | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 11 | 2019-04-03 | 2019-04-09 | C |
| 1 | 11 | 2019-05-02 | 2019-05-14 | C |
| 2 | 11 | 2019-05-20 | 2019-06-05 | D |
| 3 | 11 | 2019-03-03 | NaT | NaN |

Answer (score 0):

Use `include(column)` and append function this will help you to make the list similar then use `if(condition )` in the last cell to print `NaN`.